# NSArray's Collection Operator

Tags: objective-c

Can I obtain the index of max value using collection operator?

for example:

```
NSArray *array = @[@(0), @(10), @(2), @(3), @(48)];
NSInteger max = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@max.integerValue"];
NSInteger index = ?? <-- obtain index using collection operator
```

The index is 4 for this case.

Thanks

Comment: If you know the max you can use `indexOfObject` to find the corresponding index.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so, especially because the answer might not be unique. (i.e. there could be more than one `48` in your array.)

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
NSUInteger index = [array indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
       return (((NSNumber *)obj).integerValue == max);
}];
```